# Endnotes: issues with section title

Tags: babel, endnotes, section-titles, spanish

Using the package *endnotes* I sent the footnotes in a certain article to the penultimate section of it.

The thing is that the command

```
\theendnotes
```

makes the section title appear as **Notes** even though I added  the Spanish option of the babel package in the preamble of my TeX file: yes, I want it to appear as **Notas**! How do I manage in order for this section title to appear in Spanish?   I don't have issues with any of the other section titles in the document...

Thanks in advance for your attention and support.

Comment: `\renewcommand*{\notesname}{Notas}`

Comment: Your suggestion has been spot-on! Thanks a bunch...